# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name", although attribute is set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate 5.6 with Spring 5.3 here.

When creating predicates to fetch data from a table with this code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(aliasToBeanClass);
Root root = cq.from(aliasToBeanClass); // aliasToBeanClass is set to UmsUserRoleVOImpl
    
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(key), value)); // key is set to "userName" - this line is causing the exception
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with
> the the given name [userName] on this ManagedType
> [com.myapp.ums.business.impl.UmsUserRoleVOImpl]

But the attribute userName is included in my VO, as well as a public setter and it's mapped in my **.hbm.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myapp.ums.business.impl.UmsUserRoleVOImpl" table="ums_t_user_role"
           proxy="com.myapp.ums.common.business.UmsUserRoleVO">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="userName" type="java.lang.String" column="fk_user_id"/>
            <key-property name="roleName" type="java.lang.String" column="fk_role_id"/>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**This is my VO:**

```
public class UmsUserRoleVOImpl extends AbstractBasePropertiesImpl implements UmsUserRoleVO {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2393634151578825216L;

    private String roleName;

    private String userName;

    private List<PmPropertyVO> properties;

    public UmsUserRoleVOImpl() {

    }

    @Get(AbstractBaseProperties.ROWGUID)
    @Override
    public Long getRowguid() {
        return super.getRowguid();
    }

    @Set(AbstractBaseProperties.ROWGUID)
    @Override
    public void setRowguid(final Long rowguid) {
        super.setRowguid(rowguid);
    }

    @Get(UmsUserRoleVO.ROLE_NAME)
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    @Set(UmsUserRoleVO.ROLE_NAME)
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;

    }

    @GetCollection(value = UmsUserRoleVO.PROPERTIES, defaultObject = "com.myapp.pm.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl")
    public List<PmPropertyVO> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    @SetCollection(value = UmsUserRoleVO.PROPERTIES, defaultObject = "com.myapp.pm.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl")
    public void setProperties(List<PmPropertyVO> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof UmsUserRoleVOImpl)) {
            return false;
        }
        UmsUserRoleVOImpl user = (UmsUserRoleVOImpl) o;

        if (!(roleName.equals(user.getRoleName()))) {
            return false;
        }
        return userName.equals(user.getUserName());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 29 * result + (roleName != null ? roleName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 29 * result + (userName != null ? userName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return roleName + " " + userName;
    }

    @Get(UmsUserRoleVO.USER_NAME)
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    @Set(UmsUserRoleVO.USER_NAME)
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
}
```

There seems to be something wrong with the mapping, because Hibernate does not find any attribute of the UmsUserRoleVOImpl:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: What is `aliasToBeanClass`?

Comment: UmsUserRoleVOImpl, have added the info in the code.

Comment: Yeah that's a bug in Hibernate 5.6 which was fixed in 6.0. I don't think it's possible to access the attribute through JPA APIs when it is defined this way. Note that the annotation model does not suffer from this limitation/bug. You can create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue, but since HBM was deprecated in 6.1, I doubt this will be backported to 5.6 unless you do it.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Any idea which PR this bug was fixed with? I'd like to give it a try to backport it.

Comment: This was something that was fixed as part of the internal query model rewrite which is a major part of Hibernate 6. You won't be able to simply backport this, nor would we accept a backport since 5.6 is in maintenance mode and this is not a regression. Use the annotation model instead of hbm.xml, then you won't have to backport anything.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. In the meantime I have tested your suggestion and can confirm that annotation-based configuration solves the problem.